# Delphi AdoQuery in while statement error parameter

Tags: delphi

I have an error when i execute the AdoQuery the second time in a while statement at the assignation's parameter on Code :

In while Statement, i do only that code :

> while not tColla.Eof do
>         begin
>           ADOQUtilisateurCFGIP.Close;
>           ADOQUtilisateurCFGIP.Parameters.ParamByName('DomaineId').Value := iDomaineId;
>           ADOQUtilisateurCFGIP.Parameters.ParamByName('Code').Value :=        tColla.FieldByName('Code').AsString;
>           ADOQUtilisateurCFGIP.Open;
>           ADOQUtilisateurCFGIP.Close;
>         tColla.Next;
>         end;

The fisrt time it works, but the second time I have a variant problem on parameters Code whereas it has a good value...

Comment: Did you `Close` the dataset before setting that parameter and opening ?

Comment: What type is the ID variable?  What type is parameter?  Can you show us the SQL of the query?

Comment: Yes i close the dataset before setting that parameter. Id is a string parameter and the sql : select code from depot where Id=:ID

Comment: EVariantBadVarTypeError

Comment: what is the actual data type of "tColla.FieldByName('Code').AsString " field;

Comment: Can you try use Value changing AsString?

Comment: What's the class of tColla?

Comment: tColla is a TTable representing a Paradox' Table.